The running order of optimizers impacts predictions in PyTorch
I am running a linear regression for many optimizers. I noticed that if the SGD is activated first, the others have good accuracy. Otherwise, Adam and RMSprop present terrible adjustments.
# Generate synthetic data
X_numpy, y_numpy = datasets.make_regression(n_samples=100, n_features=1, noise=20, random_state=15)

X = torch.from_numpy(X_numpy.astype(np.float32))
y = torch.from_numpy(y_numpy.astype(np.float32))
y = y.view(y.shape[0], 1)

# Define the model
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
input_size = n_features
output_size = 1
model = nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)

# Define learning rate
learning_rate = 0.01

# Define criteria
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

# Define different optimizers
optimizers = {    
    "Adam": torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate),
    "RMSprop": torch.optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate),
    "SGD": torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate),
}

# Training loop for each optimizer
num_epochs = 100
predictions = {}
for optimizer_name, optimizer in optimizers.items():
    print(f"Optimizer: {optimizer_name}")
    predictions[optimizer_name] = []
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):        
        y_predicted = model(X)
        loss = criterion(y_predicted, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step() #update wights
        optimizer.zero_grad() #zero the gradients
    predictions[optimizer_name] = model(X).detach().numpy()

# Plotting predictions with different colors
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(X_numpy, y_numpy, 'ro', label='Original Data')
for optimizer_name, prediction in predictions.items():
    plt.plot(X_numpy, prediction, label=optimizer_name)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

The above code generates the predictions:

If I run SGD first, the following happens:
optimizers = {    
    "Adam": torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate),
    "RMSprop": torch.optim.RMSprop(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate),
    "SGD": torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate),
}


Why does it happen?

The issue is that you keep the same model for all regressions, meaning that when the first optimization ends, you will proceed with the next one using a trained model. It happens that the learning rate is only working for SGD (it seems too large for the other two optimizers), so to summarize both cases:

if you start with the other two, the model will not perform well and the model won't fit the points. On the third training (SGD), the model will be trained properly and fit the points.

if you start with SGD it will train the model and the subsequent two trainings will not change the weights much leading to a similar performance


Instead, you should reset your model and define optimizer specific learning rates:
optimizers = dict(    
    RMSprop=(torch.optim.RMSprop, 0.3),
    SGD=(torch.optim.SGD, 0.01),
    Adam=(torch.optim.Adam, 0.5),
)

for optimizer_name, (klass,lr) in optimizers.items():
    model = copy.deepcopy(model_)
    optimizer = klass(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    ## Proceed with your training loop

With the above setup, you will get the following fitting, regardless of the order of execution.


Perhaps keeping the same model for all regressions is what OP wanted?

The model being shared across runs is one thing, but what's more important is that this answer shows that only SGD fits the points well (with the current learning rate). That is the reason why the order matters too.

Yes, since the problem is convex. SGD always minimizes and other algorithms may not.

Assuming that you really want to keep optimizing your model using different optimizers, your issue is that your problem is convex.
Convexity means that you have a single minimum which is also the global minimum. It also means that the gradients become smaller and smaller as you approach the minimum point. In the convex setting, stepping towards the gradient is a reasonable idea.
So, when you start with SGD, you approach the minimum and the gradients become small. Then, the other algorithms which make a sub-optimal step (when the problem is convex) don't mess up too much since the gradients are already small.
On the other hand, if you start with say Adam, you start with making bad steps, which you later fix with SGD since for convex problems, SGD will converge to the minimum regardless of the starting point
